# How Does Random Sampling Imply No Serial Correlation with Cross-Sectional Data?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, autocorrelation, gauss-markov-theorem

I'm trying to prove that, under the random sampling, linear in parameters, and exogeneity Gauss-Markov assumptions, the error terms in $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\dots+\beta_kx_k+u$ are uncorrelated when working with cross-sectional data. So far, I have:

Since we know the sample data is independent and identically distributed, meaning drawing one observation does not make drawing another observation any more or less likely and that the observations come from the same distribution, for some observation $i\neq j$,
$$\text{Cov}(y_i,y_j)=E[y_i y_j]-E[y_i]E[y_j]=E[y_i]E[y_j]-E[y_i]E[y_j]=0$$
Thus, replacing $y$ with $\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\dots+\beta_kx_k+u$
$$0=\text{Cov}(y_i,y_j)=\text{Cov}(\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+...+\beta_kx_{ik}+u_i,\beta_0+\beta_1x_{j1}+...+\beta_kx_{jk}+u_j)$$
$$=\sum_{s=1}^k \sum_{t=1}^k \beta_s \beta_t \text{Cov}(x_{is},x_{jt}) + \sum_{s=1}^k \beta_s \text{Cov}(x_{is},u_j) + \sum_{t=1}^k \beta_t \text{Cov}(x_{jt},u_i) + \text{Cov}(u_i,u_j)$$
Using the fact that the sample is i.i.d., $$\sum_{s=1}^k \sum_{t=1}^k \beta_s \beta_t \text{Cov}(x_{is},x_{jt})=0$$ Also, by the exogeneity assumption, $$\sum_{s=1}^{k} \beta_s \text{Cov}(x_{is},u_j) + \sum_{t=1}^k \beta_t \text{Cov}(x_{jt},u_i)=0$$ Leaving us with $$\text{Cov}(u_i,u_j)=0$$

My main concerns are:

1. Am I correct that the exogeneity assumption implies $\sum_{s=1}^{k} \beta_s \text{Cov}(x_{is},u_j) + \sum_{t=1}^k \beta_t \text{Cov}(x_{jt},u_i)=0$?
2. Is everything written out correctly, and is the terminology I use accurate?